# Is it possible to have buttons for office add-ins?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I would like to ask, is it possible to add buttons in the UI for office add-ins (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/) as in with VSTO ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean in the ribbon?

[image]Yes, you can (and must per policy [4.12.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/validation-policies#4-apps-and-add-ins-behave-predictably) if submitting to AppSource) enable add-in commands for [Taskpane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands) and [Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-in-commands-for-outlook) add-ins.